Gemini API Interaction/Tutorial Setup Errors
I'm trying to go through jupyter notebook tutorial:
https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/get-started/tutorial?l&lang=python
When i run Google Colab notebook everything is ok, like it should be.
But when i try to run it on localhost sth is wrong (probably with enviroment, but i am not able to specify what exactly)
Maybe you would help me somehow.
1st error i have after block that lists models:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 for m in genai.list_models():
      2   if 'generateContent' in m.supported_generation_methods:
      3     print(m.name)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/base_ML_AI/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/models.py:191, in list_models(page_size, client, request_options)
    188     client = get_default_model_client()
    190 for model in client.list_models(page_size=page_size, **request_options):
--> 191     model = type(model).to_dict(model)
    192     yield model_types.Model(**model)
AttributeError: to_dict

2nd error i have when i try to get text from response
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 1
----> 1 to_markdown(response.text)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/base_ML_AI/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/generation_types.py:407, in BaseGenerateContentResponse.text(self)
    400 if not parts:
    401     raise ValueError(
    402         "The `response.text` quick accessor only works when the response contains a valid "
    403         "`Part`, but none was returned. Check the `candidate.safety_ratings` to see if the "
    404         "response was blocked."
    405     )
--> 407 if len(parts) != 1 or "text" not in parts[0]:
    408     raise ValueError(
    409         "The `response.text` quick accessor only works for "
    410         "simple (single-`Part`) text responses. This response is not simple text. "
   (...)
    413         "instead."
    414     )
    415 return parts[0].text

TypeError: argument of type 'Part' is not iterable

I've checked enviroments prerequisites and everything is ok (python 3.11, jupyter)
When i try to print response object they are both the same in colab and local jupyter notebook. Do you have any suggestions?

I found a discussion about one of those errors: https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/issues/154 and there is workaround for getting text from response:
(response.candidates[0].content.parts[0]._raw_part.text)

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if you found new information then put it in question, not in comments. It will be better visible, and more people may see it, so more people may help.

did you check if you use the same versions of Python and modules? Some versions of modules may have changes and may not work the same way. And sometimes modules may not work with some versions of Python - ie. when it is too old, or it is too new.

BTW: in link to Google you could remove hl=pl because it shows text in Polish instead of English and people may not know this language (PL: a nie każdy zna język polski)

I am professional software developer, i know what is print debbuging, but it didn't help or didn't provide any hints for me

certainly, my mistake - fixed

error show sproblem in line model = type(model).to_dict(model) so I would first check what type(model) it has on Colab and and on local machine. Maybe it will  help to see what can be the problem.

i'have checked it before - exactly the same object

In colab documentation there is prerequisite: Python 3.9+
But in fact their code example will not run in Python 3.11.9
I have downgraded Python to 3.10.14 and it works.
It is interesting that they didn't update their tutorial to newer version of python.
